# How to fix corrupted navigation in SharePoint Online?

Tags: navigation

My left-side navigation is corrupted. I have tried editing the links and removing them all.  The problem is that when I click on "Home", everything is OK (top image section). The same is true for when I click on "Clinician" (bottom image section).

When I click on "CAPS", the navigation also displays CAPS in bold at the bottom of the list.  *How can I remove this?*  I have edited the Navigation under the Parent site and tried to delete and the re-add, but it still comes back.  If I set the title to "CAPS2", then "CAPS" will appear at the bottom as this is a sub-site.

[image: SharePoint Online Navigation Corruption]

**EDIT: This is what the Navigation Settings looks like for CAPS subsite:**

[image: CAPS Navigation Settings]

**EDIT 2: This is what the Navigation Settings looks like for Top Level:**

[image: Top Level Nav Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings in the CAPS -> Site Settings -> Navigation seems to have fixed the problem. However, I am not sure why.

[image: Working Nav Settings]

Answer (score 1):

When you click CAPS it takes you to that subsite, and that subsite likely has a different navigation setting than the parent "Home" site or other sites like Clinician.

While you're on the CAPS site itself, go to Site Settings - Navigation and ensure that site is set to inherit the parent sites navigation settings. Or ensure that the CAPS site doesn't have customized navigation that is explicitly adding a separate link for itself.

If that doesn't work, create another subsite at the same level as CAPS and see if that has the same behaviour or if it works as you would expect. If so, maybe try deleting CAPS and recreating it? Though this shouldn't be necessary.

EDIT:

If you HAVE to manually add the links like you've done above, try hovering over the CAPS link that it's adding and change your manually added link Url to match that EXACTLY. This may trick it into seeing it's already there.

Comment: See my edit; I posted those settings. As far as I can tell, these look like what you suggested.

Comment: And what about the parent site's settings?

Comment: See Edit 2. These are the top level parent Nav settings.

Comment: Ya, it looks correct to me. The only thing might be that you're manually adding the links for everything instead of having it auto-add subsites and whatnot. The manually added CAPS link is different from the automatically added one, but it shouldn't be adding itself if it's inheriting these settings. Try my other suggestion, recreate it? Or is this a test case and production is having the same problem?

Comment: I have narrowed it now to "Quick Launch". On CAPS -> Site Settings -> Nav Elements, if I uncheck "Enable Quick Launch", then there are no duplicates, but also no navigation whatsoever. Is there another place to edit Quick Launch settings in more detail?

Comment: That's just hiding the nav altogether, but you're right, it is the Quick Launch nav that's having the issue ;) Check the edit in my original response.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Changing the "Current Navigation" option to one of the "Structural Navigation" options, hitting Save, then going back to Navigation and changing back to "same as parent" fixed the problem for me.